# Node.js cannot find directory

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to deploy an open source project written in Node.js and available at github (https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lov).

When I am trying to run the app, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory "undefined/app/views" at Function.app.render (/home/me/Documents/lov/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:493:17)
```

I know somewhat the error comes from the following piece of code: `app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views')` because config.root isn't defined, so I wanted to know where should I define this.

Does Node.js do it automatically?

Comment: [This perhaps](https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lov#install)?

Comment: normally the directory structure is dynamic and in the config.js i see it as dynamic

Comment: You have to rename `config/config.example.js` to `config/config.js`, and update the file accordingly ^^

Comment: i did it, i did rename the file, the mods are optional, i.e. if you want to change the mail setting or postmark

Comment: [The `config` object imported in `server.js`](https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lov/blob/master/server.js#L28) comes from aforementioned file. So you should just add `root` : `someDir` (namely [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd)) to `development`  (and the other envs accordingly).

Comment: i tried it, it crashes

Comment: I'm sorry but you were right, adding a key in the development object solve the problem, thanks

Comment: I posted it as an answer ^^

Comment: thanks, marked as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `config` object imported in `server.js`](https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lov/blob/master/server.js#L28) comes from [`config/config.js` file](https://github.com/pyvandenbussche/lov/blob/master/config/config.example.js).

So you should just add `root : someDir` (namely `process.cwd()`) to development (and the other envs accordingly), see:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    root: process.cwd()
...
```